# Dynamic text bolding with javascript

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using the jquery cycle library to render a picture slideshow on a webpage.

I have 5 pictures I want to scroll through and each one has a blurb of text I want to bolden when it is displaying.

i am not sure if it makes it simpler, but the order will always be the same, and I have a callback method from the cycle.

so, on every callback, how can I bolden one of five blurbs of text?  and yes it has to loop back to the first one.

The text i need to bold is currently displayed like this within a 'slideshow' div:

```
<div id="column slideshow">

           **slideshow magic here*

                    <ul>
                    <li>blurb1</li>
                    <li>blurb2</li>
                         ...
                    </ul>
</div>
```

I am wondering how to even approach this problem, I am very new to frontend devel and javascript.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just change the CSS for your `li` elements so that the text is bold? Not sure why you need to do this dynamically?

Comment: can you create a fiddle? I think I am not getting your query exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `active` class to the current element in your slideshow with the `after` and `before` callbacks, and then style that class with `font-weight: bold`.

**JavaScript**

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    after: function(el, nextEl) {
        $(nextEl).addClass('active');
    },
    before: function(el) {
        $(el).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#slideshow li.active { 
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: This almost works!  Thanks! The problem is that the rest of the text disappears and it just makes my text act like the slideshow (only shows one blurb at a time, the rest are invisible + their opacity is set to 0 if they arent the active picture and fades into the next)
I would like all the blurbs to remain in their positions but just bolden/unbolden as they are cycled through.  Any idea?